# Sinon stub private variable in typescript?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon, stubbing

I would like to stub a private variable inside a class

```
class IPC {
    private publisher: redis.RedisClient;
    constructor() {
        this.publisher = redis.createClient();
    }

    publish(text: string) {
        const msg = {
            text: text
        };

        this.publisher.publish('hello', JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
}
```

How can I stub the private variable `publisher` , inside this class?
so I could test the code as shown below

```
it('should return text object', () => {
    const ipc = sinon.createStubInstance(IPC);
    ipc.publish('world!');

    // this will throw error, because ipc.publisher is undefined
    assert.deepStrictEqual({
        text: 'world!'
    }, ipc.publisher.getCall(0).args[0]) 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to stub a private variable, and this is not the right way to do it, you could see the discussion below with Christian Johansen

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinonjs/ixtXspcamg8

The best approach, is to inject any dependency into the constructor, once we refactor the code, we could easily stub the dependency with our required behaviour

```
class IPC {    
    constructor(private publisher: redis.RedisClient) {

    }


    publish(text: string) {
        const msg = {
            text: text
        };


        this.publisher.publish('hello', JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
}



it('should return text object', () => {
    sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient')
        .returns({
            publish: sinon.spy()
        });
    const publisherStub = redis.createClient();


    const ipc = new IPC(publisherStub)
    ipc.publish('world!');


    // this is working fine now
    assert.deepStrictEqual({
        text: 'world!'
    }, publisherStub.publish.getCall(0).args[0])

    sinon.restore(redis.createClient)
})
```

Comment: You could also use something like [rewire][1] to which allows you to monkey patch / stub private functions/vars

Answer (score 4):

You can use *type assertion* in order to get access to the private variable. Like:

```
(ipc as any).publisher
```

Comment: but how can i stub it?

Comment: Do you mean: `sinon.stub(ipc, 'publisher');`?

Comment: i would like to test my code as shown above, but i cant achieve it, it will complain `Cannot read property 'getCall' of undefined`, so I dont know how to achieve the test I wanted..

Comment: Then the result of `createStubInstance` is not what you think it is. I would suggest debugging `ipc`.

Comment: i think is more like how can i test the code in such cases, is it something achievable or not..

Comment: I a language with real access modifier (like Java) it's not possible. If you want to tests stuff like that it should be public. In the case of TypeScript it is possible, because the modifier are only development-time modifiers, not runtime.

Comment: even, i change it to public, i still have problem, it complains `Attempted to wrap object property publisher as function`

Comment: Maybe `sinon.createStubInstance` doens't create the instance correctly. Did you check?

Comment: i posted the answer above, which requires a change in my approach